# How to add GoBackSupport to three WebView Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview, back-button

this is my situation:
I have **three WebView `Fragments`** and if I press the `BackButton` my application closes. But I want these `webView` `Fragments` to `goBack` to the **previous page**. I tried:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

But it still **does not work** in my `Fragments`.
How to make these `webview` `Fragments` `goBack`?

Addition: To handle my `NavigationDrawer`, there already is this code in my `MainActivity.class`:

```
@Override

    public void onBackPressed() {

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) 
findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {

            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

            } else {

            super.onBackPressed();

        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onBackPressed() {
        webView.goBack();
        return true;
}
```

try this

Comment: Your code does not work in my situation please find my edited code @TaoBit